# Generate new file with specific structure from text file

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, ksh

On Linux I have the file `orig-file.txt`. This file include 4 fields now, but they could be less or more (this file is generated by other application).

What is the best option to translate the `orig-file.txt` to a file like `output-file.txt` file (it could be with a shell script or awk, etc.)

#### orig-file.txt

```
CREATE_TIMESTAMP              TELEPHONE_NUMBER             ID TYPE
-------------------           -------------------- ---------- -----------------
24-09-2009 16:17:45           33633333333                  20 other_mmm_phone
24-09-2009 17:45:07           33644444444                  20 other_mmm_phone
07-10-2009 10:45:49           12312312312                  20 legacyphone
07-10-2009 11:46:38           59320000043                  20 other_mmm_phone
```

#### output-file.txt

```
CREATE_TIMESTAMP -> 24-09-2009 16:17:45
TELEPHONE_NUMBER -> 33633333333
ID               -> 20
TYPE             -> other_mmm_phone



---



CREATE_TIMESTAMP -> 24-09-2009 16:17:45
TELEPHONE_NUMBER -> 33633333333
ID               -> 20
TYPE             -> other_mmm_phone

---
```

example from awk lang -( but its not work -:(

```
# awk 'NR>2 {
 > printf "\
 > %-16s -> %s\n\
 > %-16s -> %s\n\
 > %-16s -> %s\n\
 > %-16s -> %s\
 > \n\n\n---\n\n\n",\
 >         "CREATE_TIMESTAMP", $1" "$2,\
 >         "TELEPHONE_NUMBER", $3,\
 >         "ID", $4,\
 >         "TYPE", $5}\
 > '   orig-file.txt
awk: newline in string near line 2
awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: illegal statement near line 3
awk: newline in string near line 7
```

Comment: Neither your original nor the output file are CSV here.

Comment: OK see my update ( I delete the CSV word ) you right not CSV but other file with specific structure

Comment: Hm. I'm sorry for picking these words, but this is a stupid file structure to manipulate. If it were a CSV file it'd be super easy, but this here is almost impossible to parse. Can't you get the data in another format?

Comment: who is stupied file - orig-file.txt ?
or output-file.txt ? - what your seggestion ? please give me other example to what the best format that I can to get from orig-file.txt
file ?

Comment: `output-file.txt` is a bad format in my eyes. It is a lot less clear to even read manually than `orig-file.txt` imho.

Comment: What I meant is the input, actually, because it's based on columns of varying with, not delimiting the fields properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some plain ksh:

```
{
  read t1 t2 t3 t4
  maxlen=$(printf "%s\n" ${#t1} ${#t2} ${#t3} ${#t4} | sort -n | tail -1)
  fmt=$(printf "%%-%ds -> %%s" $maxlen)
  read line
  while read date time tel id type; do
    printf "$fmt\n" $t1 "$date $time" $t2 $tel $t3 $id $t4 $type
    print "\n\n\n---\n\n"
  done
} < orig-file.txt
```

**Update** for flexible number of fields:

I substitute the space in the datetime field to make things easier to parse

```
sed '3,$s/ /@@/' orig-file.txt | 
{
    read line
    set -A headings $line
    max=0
    for head in "${headings[@]}"; do (( max < ${#head} )) && max=${#head}; done
    fmt=$(printf "%%-%ds -> %%s" $max)

    read line

    while read line; do
        set -A fields $line
        i=0
        while (( i < ${#headings[@]} )); do
            printf "$fmt\n" ${headings[$i]} ${fields[$i]} | sed 's/@@/ /'
            (( i=i+1 ))
        done
        print "\n\n\n---\n\n"
    done
}
```

Comment: ok very cool - but what I will do if my file will contain 5 or 6 fields and not 4 - can we create more Flexible syntax ?? that support any numbers of fields ??? ( for example I have parameter that defined the number of fields - NUM_OF_FIELDS )

Comment: example example [[ $NUM_OF_FIELDS -eq 4 ]] && read t1 t2 t3 t4 or [[ $NUM_OF_FIELDS -eq 5 ]] && read t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 ...etc

Comment: @yael, updated to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job in this case. Trivial modification needed if more fields are added.

```
awk 'NR>2{
    printf "\
%-16s -> %s\n\
%-16s -> %s\n\
%-16s -> %s\n\
%-16s -> %s\
\n\n\n---\n\n\n",\
        "CREATE_TIMESTAMP", $1" "$2,\
        "TELEPHONE_NUMBER", $3,\
        "ID", $4,\
        "TYPE", $5}\
' orig-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

"CREATE_TIMESTAMP" needs both `$1` and `$2` since the date itself is whitespace separated.

---

It can be modified to read the field names from the header, but there is the problem with the date being whitespace separated. If other fields also are allowed to contain whitespace, manual modifications will always be needed to compensate such as in the `$1" "$2` case.

Comment: but how to build this awk in to my ksh script ? , second what I need to add in case we have five fields or more ?

Comment: @yael: just as you would do with any other tool. Pipe it, or let it read from a temp file, and so on. This is not in your current question scope.

Comment: ok but see my update awk not work on ksh shell ?

Comment: @yael: I use a backslash at the end of some lines to be able to continue writing on the line below for clarity in presentation. Just remove all backslashes that end lines, and then remove all line breaks to write the entire command on a single line. This should work universally.